# Find an element in stdClass object array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to find an element from an array. I know about `in_array()` method, but it does not work for this kind of array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12
    )
)
```

I have tried:

```
if(in_array($id, $some_array)) {
     echo "find";
} else {
    echo "not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your array doesn't contain id's as such, but objects that have only 1 property, called `id`.
Assuming your data is the result of a query, consider changeing the fetch-mode, as it is probably set to `object` ATM.

For now:

```
$msg = 'not found';
foreach($some_array as $obj)
{
    if ($obj->id == $id)
    {
        $msg = 'found';
        break;
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

Alternatively, if you don't wish to mess with the fetch-mode, you could use `array_map`:

```
function toArray($obj)
{
    $obj = (array) $obj;//cast to array, optional
    return $obj['id'];
}
$idArray = array_map('toArray', $some_array);
if (in_array($id, $idArray))
{
    $msg = 'found';
}
```

Play around with array functions and callbacks until you find something that works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through it with foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and check each item's properties:

```
foreach($some_array as $item) {
    if($item->id === 11) {
        // We've found item #11!
    }
}
```